# Delete range of lines when line number of known or not in unix using head and tail?

Tags: shell, unix, ksh, text-processing

This is my sample file.

I want to do this.

1. I have fixed requirement to delete 2nd and 3rd line keeping the 1st line.
2. From the bottom, I want to delete above 2 lines excluding last line, as I wouldn't know what my last line number is as it depends on file.

Once I delete my 2nd and 3rd line 4th line should ideally come at 2nd and so on, same for a bottom after delete.

I want to use head/tail command and modify the existing file only. as Changes to write back to the same file.

Sample file text format.

Input File

```
>     This is First Line
>     Delete Delete Delete This Line
>     Delete Delete Delete This Line
>     ..
>     ..
>     ..
>     ..
>     Delete Delete Delete This Line
>     Delete Delete Delete This Line
>     This is Last Line, should not be deleted It could be come at any line
```

number (variable)

Output file (same file modified)

```
This is First Line
..
..
..
..
This is Last Line, should not be deleted It could be come at any line number (variable)
```

Edit - Because of compatibility issues on Unix (Using HP Unix on ksh shell) I want to implement this using head/tail/awk. not sed.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, could you please post more clear sample Input_file and sample expected output file too in code tags please.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Added more inputs, thanks for suggestions.

Comment: `sed '2,3d' file.txt | tac | sed '2,3d' | tac` maybe?

Comment: @MarkSetchell tac isn't supported in HP unix version, I want to implement this using head and tail only.

Comment: @Minsec, and you don't even have `sed` or `awk` on your system?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I've both but options like grouping in sed and  `sed -i` do not work on our system.

Comment: `perl -e 'print reverse <>' file.txt` is a good substitute for `tac` - assuming you have Perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding solution as per OP's request to make it genuine solution.

***Approach:*** In this solution OP could provide lines from starting point and from ending point of any Input_file and those lines will be skipped.

***What code will do:*** I have written code in that way it will generate an `awk` code as per your given lines to be skipped then and will run it too.

```
cat print_lines.ksh
start_line="2,3"
end_line="2,3"
total_lines=$(wc -l<Input_file)

awk -v len="$total_lines" -v OFS="||" -v s1="'" -v start="$start_line" -v end="$end_line" -v lines=$(wc -l <Input_file) '
BEGIN{
  num_start=split(start, a,",");
  num_end=split(end, b,",");
  for(i=1;i<=num_start;i++){
    val=val?val OFS "FNR=="a[i]:"FNR=="a[i]};
  for(j=1;j<=num_end;j++){
    b[j]=b[j]>1?len-(b[j]-1):b[j];
    val=val?val OFS "FNR=="b[j]:"FNR=="b[j]};
print "awk " s1 val "{next} 1" s1" Input_file"}
' | sh
```

Change `Input_file` name to your actual file name and let me know how it goes then.

---

Following `awk` may help you in same(Since I don't have Hp system so didn't test it).

```
awk -v lines=$(wc -l <Input_file) 'FNR==2 || FNR==3 || FNR==(lines-1) || FNR==(lines-2){next} 1'  Input_file
```

**EDIT:** Adding non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk -v lines=$(wc -l <Input_file) '
FNR==2 || FNR==3 || FNR==(lines-1) || FNR==(lines-2){
next}
1
'  Input_file
```

Comment: If going forward I want to delete last 30 lines then i need to add `lines-1 to lines-30` manually which will make this script a pretty longer.

Comment: @Minsec : Your problem is very specific that it is not going to be of much benefit to many here.. That said you should consider tools like perl

Comment: @Minsec, please run my first code, `start_line="2,3` is the variable where you need to give all lines you want to skip from starting of the Input_file and variable named `end_line="2,3"` is the one where you need to give line numbers from last of Input_file which you want to skip. Please go through it and let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

**`wc`** + **`sed`** solution:

```
len=$(wc -l inpfile | cut -d' ' -f1)
sed "$(echo "$((len-2)),$((len-1))")d; 2,3d" inpfile > tmp_f && mv tmp_f inpfile
```

---

```
$ cat inputfile
>     This is First Line
>     ..
>     ..
>     ..
>     ..
>     This is Last Line, should not be deleted It could be come at any line
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  awk '{printf "%d\t%s\n", NR, $0}' < file | sed '2,3d;N;$!P;D' file
```

The awk here serves the purpose of providing line numbers and then passing the output to the sed which uses the line numbers to do the required operations.

%d : Used to print the numbers. You can also use '%i'

'\t' : used to place a tab between the number and string

%s : to print the string of charaters

'\n' : To create a new line

NR : to print lines numbers starting from 1

For sed 
N: Read/append the next line of input into the pattern space.

$! : is for not deleting the last line

D : This is used when pattern space contains no new lines normal and start a new cycle as if the d command was issued.  Otherwise, delete text in the pattern space up to the specified lines, and restart cycle with the resultant pattern space, without reading a new line of input.

P : Print up to the first embedded newline of the current pattern space.This 
prints the lines after removing the subjected lines.

Comment: Thanks but If I want to delete 2,3 (total 2 lines) from the top and from bottom i want to delete 6 lines this won't work.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

Perl suggestion... read whole file into array `@L`, get index of last line. Delete 2nd last, 3rd last, 3rd and 2nd line. Print what's left.

```
perl -e '@L=<>; $p=$#L; delete $L[$p-1]; delete $L[$p-2]; delete $L[2]; delete $L[1]; print @L' file.txt
```

Or, maybe a little more succinctly with `splice`:

```
perl -e '@L=<>; splice @L,1,2; splice @L,$#L-2,2; print @L' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to have some flexibility a `ksh script` approach may work, though little expensive in terms of resources :

```
#!/bin/ksh
[ -f "$1" ] || echo "Input is not a file" || exit 1
total=$(wc -l "$1" | cut -d' ' -f1 )
echo "How many lines to delete at the end?"
read no
[ -z "$no" ] && echo "Not sure how many lines to delete, aborting" && exit 1
sed "2,3d;$((total-no)),$((total-1))d" "$1" >tempfile && mv tempfile "$1"
```

And feed the file as argument to the script.

**Notes**

- This deletes second and third lines.
- Plus `no` number of lines from last excluding last as read from user.

  ---

<sup>**Note:** My `ksh` version is `93u+ 2012-08-01`</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I enjoyed this task and wrote `awk` script for more scaleable case (huge files).

Reading/scanning the input file once (no need to know line count), not storing the whole file in memory.

`script.awk`

```
BEGIN { range = 3}    # define sliding window range
{lines[NR] = $0}      # capture each line in array
NR == 1 {print}       # print 1st line
NR > range * 2{       # for lines in sliding window range bottom
    print lines[NR - range]; # print sliding window top line
    delete lines[NR - range];   # delete sliding window top line
}
END {print}           # print last line
```

running:

```
awk -f script.awk input.txt
```

`input.txt`

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
line 7
line 8
line 9
line 10
```

output:

```
line 1
line 4
line 5
line 6
line 7
line 10
```